# PHP MySQL - Validate email in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

currently I do a checking function to know email already exist or not in db. If exist then error, if not update data. But if existing user edit their data such as `weight`. Then it will give error because it detect email already exist. But the user only edit the `weight` data, not the `email`. can anyone help me how to solve this problem or have any recommendation to do this part. I'm using a CodeIgniter framework.

This is my controller

```
if (!empty($this->input->post()))
        {
            $data["weight"] = $this->input->post("weight");
            $data["height"] = $this->input->post("height");
            $data["username"] = $this->input->post("username");
            $data["email"] = $this->input->post("email");
            
            if (strlen($this->input->post("username")) < 6)
            {
                $result = $this->Global_model->GenerateOutputMsgArray("0", "Username should be at least 6 alphanumerics, please try again.");
            }
            elseif (!$this->Profile_model->ValidateEmail($this->input->post()))
            {
                $result = $this->Global_model->GenerateOutputMsgArray("0", "Email has been taken, please try another.");    
            } else {
                $result["status"] == "1";
                
                $this->Profile_model->UpdateProfile($data["weight"], $data["height"], $data["username"], $data["email"]);
                
                $result = $this->Global_model->GenerateOutputMsgArray("1", "Your profile has been updated.", $data);
            }
```

this is my model (validate email function and update data)

`````````````````
public function ValidateEmail($post) 
    {
        $stat = "0";
        $msg = "";
        $data = array();
        $output = array();
        $query = $this->db->get_where("user", array("email" => $post["email"]));
        $result = $query->row();
        $result = (array)($result);
        
        return ($result) ? false : true;
    } 


    function UpdateProfile($weight, $height,$username, $email)
    {
    $data= array(
            "weight" => $weight,
            "height" => $height,
            "username" => $username,
            "email" => $email
        );
        
        $this->db->where("user_id", $this->session->userdata("user_id"));
        $this->db->update("user", $data);
    }
````````````````
`````````````````

Comment: please read [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), this is fundamental knowledge!

Comment: @Vickel noted, thanks. i'll read this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be having user_id with email.

Try with this one.

```
public function ValidateEmail($post) 
{
    $stat = "0";
    $msg = "";
    $data = array();
    $output = array();
    $query = $this->db->get_where("user", array("email" => $post["email"]));
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $query->row();
        if($result->user_id == $this->session->userdata("user_id")){
            return false; // force doesn't exist
        }else{
            return true; // exists
        }
    }else{
        return false; // as there is no row returned. it will return as doesn't exist
    }
}
```